# Why are contacts not passing an engagement split?

Tags: journeybuilder

I have a journey where everyone is being sent an email followed by a wait and an engagement activity on some specific clicks.

Only 60% are passing the engagement split. They are not in the wait and they have not unsubscribed or been suppressed. The email is being sent and opened successfully.

Those who do not click should go down the no path, but almost 1,000 people seem to have gone missing. Does anyone know what might be happening here?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

really great question !!

As always, the interpretation of the explanations by Salesforce  can be quite confusing.

So your 'Yes' click activity path is taking everyone who has clicked on the Links you have configured to monitor.

Your 'No' path takes everyone who has bounced, or not clicked on any links.

Your delta is because you are monitoring only a select number of links, so a customer could have clicked on a different link to the one you are monitoring. 
Therefore the customer would have engaged, they wouldn't go down the 'No' path, but they wouldn't go down the first path as it's not a link you have monitored.

You would have to create a 3rd path, for the other links you want to monitor and push them down that path and then all the numbers should balance